# Swagger UI not working with JSON configuration

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I have removed the @EnableSwagger2 & io.springfox:springfox-swagger2 dependency so as to not use the traditional swagger related annotations and instead use a JSON file.

I have changed the Swagger from annotations based to JSON based using the details shared here : [Overcoming Swagger Annotation Overload by Switching to JSON](https://dzone.com/articles/overcoming-swagger-annotation-overload-by-switchin)

But now it is showing [image: Error]

Can someone help me with what may be causing the issue?

Comment: @helen No, actually all those questions are using the '@EnableSwagger2' and related annotations but I want to use the JSON instead of those. Reference : https://dzone.com/articles/overcoming-swagger-annotation-overload-by-switchin

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the swagger dependency in the Pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I think might be this can be the reason it is not opening the Swagger UI.
Please try to create the bean in the configuration file so that swagger can run it properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }}
```

Comment: I had that dependency and it worked just fine, but I am trying to do the same without this dependency and any kind of swagger related annotations. Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/overcoming-swagger-annotation-overload-by-switchin